# Using a single file for Log4net from multi process?

Tags: c#, log4net

I have a problem with Log4net. I want to use Log4net in many process and just using a single file log. I had google and trying to add **log4net.Appender.FileAppender+InterProcessLock** or **log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock** but it cannot work.
I config Log4net by c# code:

```
 RollingFileAppender appender = new RollingFileAppender();
            string logFilePath = Path.Combine(folder);
            appender.File = Path.Combine(logFilePath, fileName);
            appender.AppendToFile = true;
            appender.RollingStyle = RollingFileAppender.RollingMode.Size;
            appender.MaxSizeRollBackups = maxSizeRollBackups;
            appender.MaxFileSize = Convert.ToInt64(maxFileSize * 1024 * 1024);
            appender.StaticLogFileName = true;
            log4net.Layout.PatternLayout patternLayout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout();
            patternLayout.Header = GetHeader(continueFile);
            patternLayout.ConversionPattern = conversionPattern;
            patternLayout.ActivateOptions();
            appender.Layout = patternLayout;
            appender.ActivateOptions();
            appender.LockingModel = new FileAppender.InterProcessLock();

            //FileAppender aa = new FileAppender();

            try
            {
                Hierarchy hierarchy;

                if (isDesignTime)
                {
                    hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository() as Hierarchy;
                    //hierarchy = LogManager.CreateRepository(loggerName) as Hierarchy;
                }
                else if (HasRepository(Tracer))
                {
                    hierarchy = LogManager.GetRepository(loggerName) as Hierarchy;
                }
                else
                {
                    hierarchy = LogManager.CreateRepository(loggerName) as Hierarchy;
                }

                hierarchy.Root.AddAppender(appender);
                hierarchy.Configured = true;


                //configure the logging at the root.  
                hierarchy.Root.Level = Level.All;
                }
}
```

My app will create a new process to run something on it.

How to config log4net for this case?

Comment: What do you mean by "cannot work"?

Comment: The [log4net FAQ covers this](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/faq.html#single-file) and has this to say on the subject - "Before you even start trying any of the alternatives provided, ask yourself whether you really need to have multiple processes log to the same file, then don't do it ;-)."